# Multiple classes basics, putting a print class into the main method

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to see the basics for what is required to call in a second class, because tutorials and the book I am using are over-complicating it by using user input right now.

So here is what I tried. First is my main class and the second is the class I tried to call into the main method portraying just a simple text.

```
public class deck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    edward test = new edward();
    System.out.print(test);
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
public class edward {
    public void message(int number) {
        System.out.print("hello, this is text!");   
    }
}
```

How come this doesn't work?

If you could try to explain what I am doing or how this works a bit in detail that would be nice. I'm having a hard time with this part and getting a bit discouraged.

Comment: Follow Java Naming Convention. In Java, classes are capitalized: it should be `Deck`, not `deck` and `Edward`, not `edward`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not work because you are printing a wrong thing: rather than printing `test`, you should call a method on it, like this:

```
public class deck {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        edward test = new edward();
        test.message(123);
    }
}
```

`message(int)` is a method (more specifically, an *instance* method). You call instance methods by specifying an instance on which the method is to be called (in your case, that is `test`), the name of the method, and its parameters.

The other kind of methods is `static` - i.e. like `main`. These methods do not require an instance, but they cannot access instance properties either.

Comment: @user3107180 Because your `message` method takes an `int` parameter. Even though the parameter is unused, you must specify some value for it in order for the compiler to resolve the method correctly. This is because you are allowed to "overload" a name by providing multiple definitions of method with the same name and different parameters.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class deck
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        edward test = new edward(); //1
        System.out.print(test); //2
    }
}
```

In line `1`, you create a new `edward` object called `test`.
In line `2`, you `print` the object itself. According to [the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29), `print(Object)`

> Prints an object. The string produced by the `String.valueOf(Object)` method is translated into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

I'm guessing that the output looked something like: `edward@672563`. That is because `String.valueOf(obj)` returns the type of `obj` (`edward`), followed by the character `@`, followed by the location in memory of `obj` (672563).

---

Here is some code that should do what you are attempting:

```
public class Deck //all class names should be capitalized
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Edward test = new Edward();
        test.message(); //1
    }
}

public class Edward
{
    public void message() //`message` doesn't need a parameter
    {
        System.out.print("hello, this is text!");
    }
}
```

In line `1`, you call `test`'s method `message()`. Calling a method executes the code that is in that method, so `test.message()` executes the line

```
System.out.print("hello, this is text!");
```

---

Here is a different way of doing the same thing:

```
public class Deck
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Edward test = new Edward();
        System.out.println(test.message); //1
    }
}

public class Edward
{
    public String message = "hello, this is text!"; //2
}
```

In line `2`, you create a new `String` "field" with the value of `"hello, this is text!"`.
In line `1`, you print the value of the field `message` contained in the object `test`.

If there are other parts of this code that you don't understand, feel free to comment on this answer!

Answer (score 4):

Just an additional hint.

Every class in Java is derived from the java built in class "Object".

This common class offers some common methods.

In your case the method

```
public String toString()
```

is from interest.

You can override this method in your class edward and return the String you want.

```
public class edward {

    @override
   public String toString() {
        return "hello, this is text!"

   }
```

}

If you now use an object of class edward (test)t within the main method like you did it in your sample code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          edward test = new edward();
          System.out.println(test);
    }
```

Then the text returnrd by the overriden toString() method would be printed out. 
You use in this case the possibility to override methods from a super class (Object) and a subclass (edward).

Generally you would use the toString nethod to output the values of the fields (properties) of an object to show its current state.

If you not override the toString method you would get a String like eg this @ae23da which represents the current adress of the object test in memory.